# How can I cover up a <div>'s border with another <div>?

Tags: css, z-index

I am trying to move [GCLI](https://github.com/mozilla/gcli)'s input from the bottom of the page to the top. However, I can't get it to look quite right. **Why can't I get the `.gcli-panel-connector` <div> to cover up the `.gcli-tt` <div>'s border?** I think it has something to do with the z-index.

Please compare these two live demos:

- [Original code](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/508947/gcli/orig/index.html) where the input is at the bottom and the border is properly covered
- [Altered code](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/508947/gcli/top/index.html) where the input is at the top, but the border is not covered as desired

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for `.gcli-panel-connector` add:

```
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
top: 1px;
```

keep in mind that `z-index` [works only with positioned elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index).

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain why this worked? Position: relative to enable z-index... but why did you choose z-index 1, and why was the top property needed?

Comment: @Leftium the element you want to overlap doesn't have `z-index` value, so `z-index:1` is enough. With `top:1px` you move it `1px` down to cover the border of the other box.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Note z-index was not needed; position + top was the magic incantation

Comment: @Leftium it just work with a different method. if you remove `margin-top: -1px;` from `.gcli-panel-connector` you will see the border of the other box is visible. There isn't only one solution.

Comment: Yeah, I spent way too much time trying to get that margin magic working on the other border. Finally posted to SO, and *boom*, I get an answer ^__^